# Odd error message from ftp connecting on port 22

Tags: ftp, sftp

I am a little confused. I am trying to FTP using port 22. It says that I am connected, then that I am not connected. Here is my output:

```
dan@voldemort:~$ ftp $hname 22
Connected to <hostname>.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.1
ftp> ls
Not connected.
```

What's going on? Is it because I am using port 22? I know it's the ssh port, but that is why I am using it.

EDIT: I want to know what's going on. I am not interested in other ways of transferring files, like FTP clients. I am also looking for a command line solution. I am running Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you know what the server has available as far as ports and services on those ports? Normally you don't find an FTP serve on port 22 - it's normally an ssh server. Normally port 21 is provided by an FTP server.  You can use an SSH server to transfer files - using scp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Port 22 is for SSH, not FTP. You can't use an ordinary FTP client on port 22, you have to use an SSH-enabled FTP client.

From the Ubuntu command line, use `sftp`, not `ftp`.

Comment: So sftp is very fundamentally different from ftp, and ftp on port 22 != sftp?

Comment: Correct. SSH is an encrypted communication channel. SFTP is, as far as I know, FTP _on top of_ SSH, but merely talking to port 22 instead of 23 would not cause the connection to become secure. So something has to supply that secure layer.

Comment: Dan, SFTP is in no case an "FTP over SSH" but a completely unrelated binary protocol.

Comment: Oh ok I was mixed up about that.

Answer (score 1):

Connection to port 22 should use ssh. you may use WinSCP to connect.

Comment: Sorry, I am looking for FTP. AFAIK Putty doesn't support FTP, only SSH. You cannot transfer files with SSH. Also, putty is a Windows thing, which I am not running.

Comment: In Linux you may refer to [SFTP](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man1/sftp.1.html)